# Process terminated with status -1073741819 mid loop?

Tags: c

Beginner in C and running into a problem with a function that initializes an array.  Compiled in Code:Blocks 16.01 on Windows 10.  Specific code I'm having issues with is:

```
void initAuction(float auction[2][MAXAUCTIONITEMS]) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < MAXAUCTIONITEMS; i++) {
        auction[1][i] = -1;
        printf("\n%f\t%d\n", auction[1][i], i);
    };
    for (i = 0; i < MAXAUCTIONITEMS; i++) {
        auction[2][i] = 0;
        printf("\n\n%f\t%d", auction[2][i], i);
    }
    printf("\n%f\n", auction[2][70]);
    return;
}
```

I've set up print statements to see how far I'm getting before the crash and I make it to the second for loop but it crashes at i=140.  If I change the constant (which is equal to 1000) then the highest I can set it to without crashing is i<84 oddly enough.  What would cause the termination status -1073741819 mid loop when the first row initialized no problem but row 2 chooses to crash at around i=140.

I've tried searching on google and here and it seems the termination code isn't a very specific code since I've seen solutions from needing a return statement, trying to access something that doesn't exist, etc.  Really lost.

Comment: `float auction[2][MAXAUCTIONITEMS]`: your first dimension is of size 2, yet you index auction with `auction[2][i]`, going out of bounds. Remember, C is 0-based.

Comment: Generally, you should submit a whole program that demonstrates the error -- e.g. include a `main` that does the least amount of work to exhibit the error.

Comment: Use a debugger to solve these problems.

Comment: @Evert, tried to use the debugger, opened it in a project (since debugging single source files is apparently not supported in Code:Blocks) and was unable to actually have Code:Blocks Build my program.  It kept telling me that it wanted to build it but whenever I clicked yes it would simply ask again.

Comment: Tip for the future: when you get a strange decimal error code like `-1073741819`, convert it to hex which in this case is `0xc0000005`.  That is a recognizable status code on Windows which is an access violation error (ie., accessing memory that isn't valid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting elements of the array beyond its boundaries: the initial dimension of `auction` is `2`, the only valid values for this index are `0` and `1`.

You can fix and simplify the code this way:

```
void initAuction(float auction[2][]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXAUCTIONITEMS; i++) {
        auction[0][i] = -1;
        auction[1][i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Note that the second dimension is not part of the type of `auction`, it is ignored by the compiler.

Comment: I appreciate the response.  I'm not entirely sure why your worked(even when i corrected the indices) but I'm on a time crunch at the moment but definitely want to ask more about the differences tomorrow if that wouldn't be an issue.  Again, can not thank you enough!

Answer (score 2):

The valid indices are `auction[0][*]` and `auction[1][*]`.

Comment: So I tried your edit and it still crashes at 140 except now it seems like random indices in the second row are =to random values instead of zero.  Also, some of those indices now contain letters as well?